# Location menu in extended controls of Android Studio virtual device

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-studio-3.5

I need to import a .gpx file to my virtual device (something I'm attempting for the first time today), but I'm having a problem I can't find any reference to anywhere else. I'm either having a moment and missing something that should be obvious or there's an issue with the specific build I have that's causing an issue. I have Android Studio 3.5.3 installed and I've tried multiple different virtual devices.

All references to the menu page referenced in my title that I can find online look like this:

[image: Extended Controls with text boxes]

While my version of that page looks like this:

[image: Extended Controls with map]

That "Import GPX/KML" button always appears to be greyed out. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Eventually found the cause of this and a solution. The issue was caused by an Android emulator release that updated the Location settings to include a Google Maps based UI. Release notes here, though I've found the 29.2.11 release on 03/12 also contained the UI change: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29212-stable-google-maps-ui.html. On my Windows 10 computers this also removed the option of importing a GPX file (not sure if this was an intentional choice by Google or a bug). Not sure if it will affect Linux or Mac users but I've observed the issue on multiple Windows 10 devices.

The fix I found for the issue was to downgrade my emulator to 29.2.1. That version can be found here:

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-5889189.zip

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5889189.zip

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-5889189.zip

In Windows, next go to C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator. Those of a cautious disposition can backup this folder, but either way the package.xml file will be needed and everything else can be moved or deleted. Edit the details in the XML to match the version number of the downloaded emulator. Copy the downloaded files to this location along with the package.xml. Then just make sure not to download the update again when Android Studio is opened.

Comment: thanks, I have been looking at this issue for a couple of days now and couldn't find the solution.

Comment: update to the latest version of the emulator and you will see they have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer carlosx2 ..but I had the latest version 29.4.3 and it was faulty so I took your advice (and instructions) and went back to 29.2.1.